# Passing a font from one class to another

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I loaded a font.swf (in Flash CS5) and it works in the class I loaded the font into, but if I want to pass it to another class, how do I do that?

I tried passing it as a TextFormat instance (with the format.font = my_loaded_font) but that doesn't appear to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a font is embedded, you refer to it by its family name as a String. It need not be passed from class to class.

Comment: So if I want a textfield with my font, I can just write: new TextFormat(“My-Font-Name") anywhere in my project and it will work?

Comment: Yeah, as long as the font name matches exactly with what is specificed in the font metadata and you've embedded it anywhere else in the compiled SWF.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are global once loaded; you access them by their name in the global font list. See here:

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/Font.html#enumerateFonts()

```
import flash.text.Font;

var allFonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts(true);
```